# Neo4J - PHP Fetching Data

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I have to fetch data from neo4j graphical database using PHP. I dont know where to start from.I have to pull  out data from the properties of the nodes which come in the output. Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: Please add some more details like code blocks to your question.

Comment: Have you seen https://neo4j.com/developer/php/